# Git pull request conflict

Tags: git, conflict, pull-request

I am very new to git and I am worried my codes are going to ruin the master project.

1 - I forked a new repo from master project into my account. 
And I changed some codes and did pull request to master in last week.

2 - Again, this week, I did the same. I changed some codes and did pull request to master project but it has a conflict with a master project.

The owner of master project said that "someone has changed in the master project and you need to accept it".
But I have no idea how to accept it.

I tried these commands

> **git pull** // This returns **Already up-to-date**.
>   **git checkout master** // This returns **Already on 'master'**.
>   **git merge origin/master** // This returns **Already up-to-date**.
>   **git status** // This returns **nothing to commit, working tree clean**.

[See the working tree example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSUMB.jpg)

Comment: Are you using github.com?

Comment: Yes. I am using github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, it seems like you would like to pull in changes from the master repository into your repository (or vice versa).

Either way, in GitHub, you can either create a pull request to pull in changes from the head fork into your personal clone or you can configure an upstream remote to fetch changes from in your local copy. There you would merge in changes from the master repository and push these back to your fork on GitHub.

See also https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/ as a reference.

If you simply need to accept a pull request, just browse to the master repository (assuming you are someone who has write access) and check the pending pull requests.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly check out the conflicts accept the master's codes, then do in the root of the git repo

> $git add .  //Add all your changes to the git tree
>
> $git status //checking what you are adding to the git
>
> $git commit -m "fix conflicts" //add the submit comment to your submit action
>
> $git rebase //compare the codes on the master with your local master when conflicts happened, rebase will accept your lastest changes and automatically overwrite the old codes then submit to the git head.

**I am strongly suggest you to use rebase rather than merge, coz rebase is smarter then merge, when conflicts happened, the most important of rebase is that merge your git tree to the origin master tree into one, so you can continue developing with one clean git tree.**

Comment: Rebase re-writes history. Not really a good idea unless it's absolutely necessary